# 401 unauthorized when trying to get OAuth2 access token in jUnit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5

I need to write a jUnit test case, it keeps failing for "/contextpath/oauth2/token?grant_type=password".

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = UserAuthApplication.class)
class UserAuthApplicationTests {

    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private String obtainAccessToken(final String username, final String password) throws Exception {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "password");
        params.add("username", username);
        params.add("password", password);

        ResultActions result = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/userauth/oauth/token").params(params).with(httpBasic("user-test","testp"))
                        .accept("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect((ResultMatcher) content());

        String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void tokenNotGiven_whenGetSecureRequest_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/userauth/apis/v1/users").param("email", ""))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void givenValidUserCredentials_whenGetSecureRequest_thenAuthorized() throws Exception {
        String accessToken = obtainAccessToken("test@gmail.com", "test1");
        mockMvc.perform(get("/userauth/apis/v1/users")
          .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
          .param("email", ""))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
        
        mockMvc.perform(get("/userauth/apis/v1/users")
              .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
              .param("email", ""))
              .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect((ResultMatcher) content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.success", is(true)));
    }

}
```

**When, I run above test case it give me below error:**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /userauth/oauth/token
       Parameters = {grant_type=[password], username=[test@gmail.com], password=[test1]}
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json", Authorization:"Basic dXNlci1hdXRoOm1hbm9q"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"status":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

It is expected that it should generate token, As in postman even in ReactJS based app able to generate and working correctly, but it is only failing in jUnit.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of `MockMvc` is that you work with a mocked Servlet environment and case use Spring Security Test support to basically *set* the user in the `SecurityContext`. This reliefs you from preparing any tokens if you *just* want to test your HTTP endpoints.

Make sure to have the following dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then you can either use `@WithMockUser(username="mike")` on test-method level or while performing the request with `MockMvc`:

```
this.mockMvc
    .perform(get("/userauth/apis/v1/users")
      .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()
        .jwt(YOUR_JWT_HERE) // also optional
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")))) // also optional
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

If you still want to test the security flow, I would recommend to rather use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` on your test and don't use `MockMvc`. Then you can either use the auto-configured `TestRestTemplate`  or `WebTestClient` and first perform the token retrieval and then access your endpoint with a *real* Servlet environment.

Comment: I have got the similar issue. I cannot fix it. I hope you can help me. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77077657/how-to-mock-bearer-token-in-integration-test-of-spring-boot-401-unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get rieckpil answer to work for me due to this change mentioned here - https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/issues/360

If the HTTP request does not contain a token header, but the user is authenticated the security context is cleared. this causes an issue further down the filter chain as the user is checked again to see if they're authenticated, but with the context cleared they're considered to be an anonymous user, so the request will return a 401.

to work around this we can set the stateless boolean to false which will prevent the context from getting cleared.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class StatelessConfigure implements ResourceServerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }
}
```