# How to use bearer token in Integration Test for mock or other way in Spring Boot (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, mockito, integration-testing

I have a problem to use bearer token in refresh token and logout as all these two processes are tackled with bearer token in Integration Test of my Spring Boot example.

I created MockJwtTokenProvider  to create a mock bearer token for Integration test shown below

```
public class MockJwtTokenProvider {


    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "404E635266556A586E3272357538782F413F4428472B4B6250645367566B5970";
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME_MS = 3600000; // 1 hour

    public static String createMockJwtTokenForCustomer() {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims()
                .setSubject("customer_1") // Set the username as the subject
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + MockJwtTokenProvider.EXPIRATION_TIME_MS));

        claims.put("roles", Collections.singletonList("ROLE_CUSTOMER"));
        claims.put("userFullName", "customer_fullname");
        claims.put("id", 1);
        claims.put("email", "customer@bookdelivery.com");

        // Create a secret key from your actual secret key string
        SecretKey secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SECRET_KEY.getBytes());

        // Build the JWT token with the provided claims
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .signWith(secretKey, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
                .compact();

        return "Bearer " + token;
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of AuthControllerTest shown below

```
@Test
void refreshToken_ReturnSuccess() throws Exception {

    // given
    TokenRefreshRequest request = TokenRefreshRequest.builder()
            .refreshToken("validRefreshToken")
            .build();

    TokenRefreshResponse mockResponse = TokenRefreshResponse.builder()
            .accessToken("newMockedToken")
            .refreshToken("validRefreshToken")
            .build();


    String mockBearerToken = MockJwtTokenProvider.createMockJwtTokenForCustomer();

    // when
    when(authService.refreshToken(request)).thenReturn(mockResponse);

    // then
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/refreshtoken")
                    .header("Authorization", mockBearerToken)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

}

@Test
void logout_ReturnSuccess() throws Exception {

    // Given
    String mockBearerToken = MockJwtTokenProvider.createMockJwtTokenForCustomer();

    // When
    when(authService.logout(mockBearerToken)).thenReturn("success");

    // Then
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                    .header("Authorization", mockBearerToken))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(authService).logout(mockBearerToken);

}
```

I always got this issue shown below for refresh token and logout.

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"path":"","error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","status":401}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

I also use real bearer token but I got the same error.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also solved the issue by following this **approach**

1 . Define **customUserDetailsService** and **jwtUtils** in **AuthControllerTest**

```
@MockBean
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
```

2 . Define **bearer token**

```
 // given
 User mockUser = User.builder()
          .id(1L)
          .username("customer_1")
          .email("customer@bookdelivery.com")
          .role(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)
          .fullName("customer_fullname")
          .build();

  CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(mockUser);


  String accessToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

  String mockBearerToken = "Bearer " + accessToken;
```

3 . As I used **mysql** running on **docker** through **testcontainer**, the value cannot be found and I return **userDetails** with the usage of **mock**

```
when(customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("customer@bookdelivery.com")).thenReturn(userDetails);
```

Here is the final code shown below

```
class AuthControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {

@MockBean
private AuthService authService;

@MockBean
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  
 
 @Test
    void refreshToken_ReturnSuccess() throws Exception {

        // given
        User mockUser = User.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .username("customer_1")
                .email("customer@bookdelivery.com")
                .role(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)
                .fullName("customer_fullname")
                .build();

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(mockUser);


        String accessToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

        String mockBearerToken = "Bearer " + accessToken;

        TokenRefreshRequest request = TokenRefreshRequest.builder()
                .refreshToken("validRefreshToken")
                .build();

        TokenRefreshResponse mockResponse = TokenRefreshResponse.builder()
                .accessToken("newMockedToken")
                .refreshToken("validRefreshToken")
                .build();

        // when
        when(authService.refreshToken(request)).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        when(customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("customer@bookdelivery.com")).thenReturn(userDetails);

        // then
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/refreshtoken")
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, mockBearerToken)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    }

    @Test
    void logout_ReturnSuccess() throws Exception {

        // Given
        User mockUser = User.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .username("customer_1")
                .email("customer@bookdelivery.com")
                .role(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)
                .fullName("customer_fullname")
                .build();

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(mockUser);


        String accessToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

        String mockBearerToken = "Bearer " + accessToken;

        // When
        when(customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("customer@bookdelivery.com")).thenReturn(userDetails);
        when(authService.logout(mockBearerToken)).thenReturn("success");

        // Then
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, mockBearerToken))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(authService).logout(mockBearerToken);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Updated] Based on [your github repository](https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery), I see that, **in Runtime** you're using another utility class `JwtUtils` that doesn't have same structure and content like `MockJwtTokenProvider`! I think it's the reason behind your issue.

The following is *JwtUtils* class which works fine at runtime:

```java
package com.example.demo.security.jwt;

import com.example.demo.security.CustomUserDetails;
import com.example.demo.util.Identity;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Log4j2
public class JwtUtils {


    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.expireMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    private final Identity identity;

    public JwtUtils(Identity identity) {
        this.identity = identity;
    }


    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication auth) {
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        Map<String, Object> claims = userDetails.getClaims();
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    public String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .signWith(getSignInKey(),SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
                .compact();
    }

    public String generateJwtToken(CustomUserDetails customUserDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = customUserDetails.getClaims();
        claims.put(TokenClaims.ID.getValue(), customUserDetails.getId());
        return createToken(claims, customUserDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    public Claims extractClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    public Long getIdFromToken(String token){
        String idValue = extractClaims(token).get(TokenClaims.ID.getValue()).toString();
        Double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(idValue);
        return doubleValue.longValue();
    }

    public String getEmailFromToken(String token){
        return extractClaims(token).get(TokenClaims.EMAIL.getValue()).toString();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {

        log.info("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | authToken: {}", authToken);

        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignInKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            log.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String extractTokenFromHeader(String authorizationHeader) {

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've tried to run the test in debug mode, and noticed an exception:

```bash
io.jsonwebtoken.security.weakkeyexception: The verification key's size is 48 bits which is not secure enough for the HS256 algorithm
```

Which means the key is not compatible with the encryption algorithm. Try to use `JwtUtils` in your tests instead and you'll be fine.

Also, as you're using spring-security-test, you must define a mock user with `@WithMockUser` annotation. Check the following example :

```java
class AuthControllerTest  extends BaseControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @WithMockUser("customer_1")
    @Test
    void refreshToken_ReturnSuccess() throws Exception {

        User mockUser = User.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .username("customer_1")
                .email("customer@bookdelivery.com")
                .role(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)
                .fullName("customer_fullname")
                .build();

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(mockUser);

        // Generate a JWT token for the user
        String mockToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

        String mockBearerToken = "Bearer " + mockToken;

        // the rest of your method code
    }

    // your other test methods...
}
```

Comment: I revised my repo. Can you check MockJwtTokenProvider ?